# preg replace https won't work

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove `http://` & `https://`

I add this inline: `^https?://`

```
preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((^https?:////\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#(\w+)/u')
```

Try and fail, syntax error ?

Comment: yeah Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: Please provide the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you have `////` while you wanted to write `\/\/`. You should not add `^https?://` but `https?:\/\/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove `http://` and `https://` (which is your question), this will do the trick:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/)/', '', 'http://example.com');
```

If you only want to remove them if a string starts with either of those protocols:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/)/', '', 'http://example.com');
```

The `^` right after the initial delimiter means "start of the string".

Comment: Why not just use `$string = str_replace("http://", "", $string);` and `$string = str_replace("https://", "", $string);`? Much simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Why use two statements when you can do it in one? And with `preg_replace()`, you can assert that the replace should only take place if it starts with any of those protocols, not replacing all.

Comment: That's actually a good point. I was thinking of a string of text, that could contain a link. In that case the beginning modifier will not work. But I guess it doesn't make a whole lot of difference.

Comment: I do usually agree that you should keep it as simple as possible (KISS ftw), and that regex often makes it more complicated than necessary, but in this case, the regex is simple enough to be readable.

Comment: Yep. Agreed. You can do it either way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_http($url) {
 $disallowed = array('http://', 'https://');
 foreach($disallowed as $d) {
   if(strpos($url, $d) === 0) {
      return str_replace($d, '', $url);
   }
 }
 return $url;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)